# WordPress - How to find a page with slug that matches the current custom post type archive page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using the Theme Customizer to create a custom post type page. Using the following PHP code and some additional jquery I'm able to set a default Custom Post Type archive page.

```
$id = get_option('cptarchive-page'); 
$p = get_page($id); 
echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
```

This basically grabs the page I select in the Theme Customizer, finds it's ID, then the jQuery injects the content into the default archive page.

But I want to be able to set a different page for each different CPT.

Now, I have created a custom post type called Staff, and a new page called Archive Staff.

Is it possible to filter through the pages and look for a page with a title `Archive [cpt name]` (**Archive Staff** in this case), and show that page?

If it doesn't exist, then show the default one I have selected in the theme customer.

And this should work for all custom post types registered. Each CPT archive should find a page that matches their name and show that page.

**SUMMARY**

(I realized this may be unclear so here's another explanation:)

I currently have, inside the Theme Customizer, an option to select a page to use as the default Custom Post Type archive page using PHP & jQuery. Now I want to be able to automatically use a different page for each registered CPT archive **IF** a page titled "Archive [CPT name]" is published.

**EXAMPLE**

**Registered CPTs**: Staff, Practitioners

**Pages created**: Archive Practitioners

So the flow would be:

- Find all registered custom post types, excluding built-in post types (Staff, Practitioners)

  - FOR EACH registered CPT

    - If page with name “Archive [CPT name]” EXISTS:

      - get the_content
    - If NOT EXISTS:

      - Use chosen default custom archive page

So for the Staff archive, the default archive page would be used because there isn't a page called Archive Staff.

But for the Practitioners archive, the default archive page would be the Archive Practitioners page that I created.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder

Comment: @gavin thanks for that suggestion. It's close to what I'm looking for... but not quite. I updated my question with some more explanation to communicate my situation more clearly. thanks!

Comment: On what page then do you want to show your loop? Sorry, I am not familier with theme customizer at all, so probably not qualified to assist much.

Comment: @GavinSimpson the theme customizer is just for the user to choose a specific page.  This page will then be injected into the default wordpress archive page, and then using jQuery I move the loop into a specific div inside that page that was injected. and then all elements that are NOT inside that custom page that was injected will be hidden with CSS. Now showing is the_content of the custom page chosen in the Theme Customizer, with the loop inside that. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That does make sense @charlie, it just sounds like an insane way of doing things to me. I would much rather simply create my own cpt, with their own templates, all in a plugin. Then it would be simple to add the logic as per the link I posted to your own cpt class. Somewhere in your code now you will have to use get_post_type to get the cpt name, then apply your logic based on the post name.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson I know this seems totally insane, and I'm trying to figure out how to simplify it. Unfortunately, I'm just trying to customize CPT archive pages using just a plugin, so the user will be registering their own CPTs which is why I can't register them myself.